# Using Skype option for making calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, skype

Previously my dialer would give me the option of making the call through Skype, or my network. This for some reason has disappeared. It did give me the option when I send a text (of going through either Skype or Viber or network), that also stopped as of today. It does give me the option when I go through Samsungs S Voice and request it to make a call. I have cleared all defaults I can find (I do not have a dialer option - only dialer storage, all other default options are 'greyed out'), I have uninstalled and reinstalled Skype and have tried all the other advice on the forum. Would really love it if someone can help me out! I have a Samsung S3